# getting time in milliseconds from a date

Tags: tcl

Is it possible to take a string of date, such as `2013-02-26 10:45:54,082` and get the time in milliseconds from the "epoch" ? or something similar?

I know `clock scan` returns the time in seconds.
Also `clock scan` returns an error for this specific format.

I couldn't find something as I want, and I want to make sure it doesn't exists before I start creating it...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The millisecond-scale offset isn't supported by Tcl (as it is a fairly rare format in practice), but you can work around that:

```
set str "2013-02-26 10:45:54,082"
regexp {^([^\.,]*)[\.,](\d+)$} $str -> datepart millipart; # split on the last occurrence of , or . 
set timestamp [clock scan $datepart -format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" -gmt 1]
scan $millipart "%d" millis
set millistamp [expr {$timestamp*1000 + $millis}]
```

(You don't supply timezone info, so I've assumed it is UTC, i.e., “GMT”. I've also allowed for using `.` instead of `,` as a millisecond separator, as which you get depends on the locale that created the time string in the first place.)

Comment: Somehow it doesn't work for the clock scan option `-format`: **bad switch "-format": must be -base or -gmt
    while executing
"clock scan $datepart -format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" -gmt 1"**
but it works great without it