# How to convert time object with miliseconds using tcl

Tags: tcl, utc

I am converting string time to a time object but I am struggling to get the time including miliseconds.

```
set date1 "2022-01-30 00:00:08"
puts [clock scan $date1 -format {%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S} -gmt 1]
```

This is successful and gives me the correct time in utc.  But if I use `set date1 "2022-01-30 00:00:08.912"` it fails.  I can't find a switch for the `.912`.

Comment: this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464474/getting-time-in-milliseconds-from-a-date) can help you ?